# Usage of spinlock functions

Tags: c, ipc, spinlock

How do I use these functions?
I have declared lock globally.

```
pthread_spinlock_t lock;
```

Also the spinlock is initialized locally.

```
pthread_spin_init(&lock, 1); // non-zero as pshared for IPC
```

But now I want to lock my critical integer and increment it.
I have multiple processes running this in a loop:

```
while(0 != pthread_spin_trylock(&lock));
criticalInt += 1;
pthread_spin_unlock(&lock);
```

Why doesn't that work?
Also, how is the following function used?

```
pthread_spin_lock(&lock);
```

EDIT:

```
for (i=0; i < NUM_CHILDREN; i++) {

   pid[i] = fork();
   if (pid[i] == -1) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }
   if (pid[i] == 0) {
   while (criticalInt < MAXCOUNT) {
      pthread_spin_lock(&lock);
      criticalInt += 1;
      pthread_spin_unlock(&lock);
      count++;
   }
   printf("Process %i counted %i\n", i, count);

}
```

For a MAXCOUNT of 1000000 hat produces the following output:

```
    Process 3 counted 687858
    Process 0 counted 815657
    Process 1 counted 640191
    Process 2 counted 744340
```

Actually all together summed up should be 1000000. But they are not.

I get similar results if I totally delete the lock.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what behavior makes you say it doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Does your program hang? Does it produce unexpected output?

Comment: I am deeply sorry, I forgot the loop. Well it just does not lock my application at all. Semaphores work like a charm, but just not this spinlock.

Comment: What the - you're doing the spinning yourself? Just use `pthread_spin_lock` instead of that loop. The pre-edit form of your code was correct.

Comment: Also, again, what behavior makes you say it "does not lock my application at all"?

Comment: pthread_spin_lock will not return until it has acquired the lock.  Looks like that's what you're trying to achieve by looping on trylock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any typical use of POSIX threads to work, you need to use `pthread_create()` to start a new thread.  Here, you're using `fork()`, which starts a new process that does not share the same address space as the parent.

Update: @Ramiz pointed out in the comments that some pthread primitives can take advantage of shared memory regions that allow them to operate across forked processes.  This isn't a common way to use pthread stuff, but it's possible!

Comment: The criticalInt is actually shared memory.

Comment: Is "lock" in shared memory too?

Comment: No, how do I get it in there?

Comment: If you look at the typedef for pthread_spinlock_t, it's just "volatile int".  It might work if you can declare the lock the same way you declared the criticalInt.

Comment: Also, if you're using gcc, consider using __sync_fetch_and_add to atomically increment the integer instead of dealing with the locking!

Comment: This answer is *not* quite correct: you *can* use pthread_spin_lock even on forked processes, but they have to have access to the lock, e.g. via shared memory and pthread_spin_init must be done with flag PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_spin_init.3.html  However, such approach is *not* recommended.

Comment: @Ramiz you're totally right!  I've never done that, but in theory, it should work!  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the spinlock to be used by multiple *processes* and not *threads* then the spinlock itself also needs to be generated in shared process memory. The pshared value of PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED by itself is not enough for a spinlock to be shared between processes.